# PHP insert image upload url in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two way for insert image upload url in MySQL database:

One:(only filename)

`1410468094_shutterstock_130757219.jpg`

Two:(full url)

`http://localhost/nws/uploads/files/1/shutterstock_130757219.jpg`

which way is better?

Comment: Do you need the path? Then store it. If not, then don't

Comment: We have no idea what your needs are, therefore we can't offer ANY opinion that'd be useful, even if opinions were allowed on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file name is best cause if anytime you change folder name or location .

Answer (score 0):

Second way without the domain name is batter. I mean `uploads/files/1/shutterstock_130757219.jpg` is batter. Because your domain name may change over time. But you should put the file path relative to your web root directory.

Answer (score 0):

If all images will be put in the same folder you would like to leave out the path, that way you could move the images one day to S3, CDN or anywhere else and won't have to update all the records. However if the images comes from all over the Internet, you need the full path.